# Facebook permission to moderate comment

Tags: facebook

I have scenario:

- I am website with 50 pages, where I embeded facebook comment
- I created app and use fb:app_id='xxx' full code
- I list myself as admin
- As I am admin of the app, I can moderate all comment using Comment Moderation tool, http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

So what this implies is that I as user can have admin right to moderate comment. I wonder is it possible to grant that permission (comment moderation as admin) to third party app? What is name of this permission

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by third party apps? As far as i know you can only grant moderating rights to the app by adding them as admins. You can't grant them to other apps and their admins if thats what you mean.